# Most suitable place for object state validation

Tags: oop

So assuming we have class Foo with properties FirstProp and SecondProp and ThirdProp.
Business wise, the allowed values in SecondProp are dependent on the value set for FirstProp and ThirdProp's allowed values are dependent on the values of both FirstProp and SecondProp.
Where is it most suitable to put this logic?

If it is in the setter of each property then there is the fact that the class user might set he ThirdProp before the other two, would we also need to enforce the order of setting the properties then? That does not seem optimal. Also, if we are to restrict initialization of the object to parmererized constructors then this would not be practical in cases like when we are designing the object as a value type (struct) since the default constructor in a struct is always available.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd keep Foo as a pure java bean.  This has many benefits that might not be obvious at first.  One of which is you will need/want a plain setter for when you're reading/persisting this object to a database (if you are).

Instead, create a subclass of Foo, which contains the business logic.  This will separate your code into a persistence tier and a domain/business object tier.

Comment: If only I understand you correctly then making such checks in more specific classes violates LSP. Consider classic rectangle <--> square example

Comment: This is true, depending on his logic, it might be a violation of LSP.  It's really hard to be certain from his example.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to make `Foo` an immutable value object and make all necessary checks in the static factories.

```
final class Foo {
  private final SomeObject first;
  private final SomeObject second;
  private final SomeObject third;

  private Foo(SomeObject first, SomeObject second, SomeObject third) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
  }

  /* Simple Getters + equals and hashCode if necessary */

  public static Foo newInstance(SomeObject first, SomeObject second, SomeObject third) {
     if ( ! /* your condition holds */ )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

     return new Foo(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: But does this approach really prevent class users from skipping the factory and going directly to the constructor?

Comment: @MSD, constructor is private and it enforces users to use static factories. You can create such object and try by yourself. Anyways all these restrictions  can be avoided on the lower levels (of any approach).

Answer (score 0):

I'd group the property validation in a validate() method that could either be called externally before using the object (returning true if initialized correctly), or within any getters to throw an InvalidObjectStateException if they are used before the properties are set correctly.

Comment: I disagree.  The object should never be allowed to get into an invalid state.